# Remove empty fields in an array after foreach in PHP

Tags: php, foreach, array-filter

I am new to PHP. This is my code from our mailing.php. When a user submits a request, there are 5-7 select-able fields and 20-25 fields that end up not being selected. The output lists all fields and values regardless of whether they are empty or have been selected. I understand I need to use either `unset` or `array_filter`, but cannot figure out how and where I need to insert into code.

```
if($_POST && count($_POST)) {

    $body = '';

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        $body .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";

    mail("email@email.com", "Email Received at email@email.com", $body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
if($_POST && count($_POST)) {
     $_POST = array_filter($_POST);
     $body = '';

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        $body .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";

    mail("email@email.com", "Email Received at email@email.com", $body);
```

OR

```
if($_POST && count($_POST)) {
     $body = '';
     foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $trim_value = trim($value);
        if (!empty($trim_value)){
            $body .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";
        }

     }
mail("email@email.com", "Email Received at email@email.com", $body);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your a life saver. I was putting |$_POST = array_filter($_POST);| after foreach loop instead of before.

Answer (score 0):

Just before foreach loop you should use this

```
$_POST = array_filter($_POST);
```

Another option is to use a conditional inside foreach loop

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    if ($value != '' && $value != null)
        $body .= $key . ": " . $value . "\r\n";
```