# PHP form: How not to send name of input if value empty?

Tags: php, forms, email

This question is edited, because i found the solution here:
[Remove empty fields in an array after foreach in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375748/remove-empty-fields-in-an-array-after-foreach-in-php)

Thanks to all of your responses. I wouldn´t have found it without your answers!

............................................

I have a simple PHP contact form. Is it possible to not send the "name" of an input text field, if its "value" is empty?

for example i have:

```
<form action="{form-action}" method="post">        
<label for="Name">{Name}</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" maxlength="100"/>

<label for="Optional">{Optional}</label>
<input type="text" name="Optional" id="Optional" maxlength="100"/>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (array($_POST)) {
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
if ($key != 'send') {
$mail .= "<span>$key</span><span>$value</span>";
}
}
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: `&& empty($_POST['Name'])` to exisiting conditional of your choice.

Comment: `if (empty($name)) { don't add to email }`

Comment: Seeing as you used the word `empty`, did you consider looking at PHP's [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)?

Comment: Just check if there is a valid value before using it.  *Always* check if user input is valid before using it in your code.

Comment: ok thx, i included && empty($_POST['Optional'])

Comment: but how can i not send the name=optional if (empty($optional) . i don´t understand

Comment: ok, thx at all for help already, i try

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple check:

```
    if (is_array($_POST)) {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'send' && ($key == 'Name' && trim($value) != '')) {
                $mail_body .= "<span>$key</span><span>$value</span>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your answer doesn't take into account a situation where a user enters the space character. The values should be trimmed.

Comment: Nice catch, I will add it.

Comment: yes something like this, i try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

if (!isset ($_POST['send']))
{
   #Form has not been sent yet
   #Create contact form
   // ....  
} 
elseif ($_POST['send'] == 1) 
{
   #Form has been sent
   #Check user input
   $noerrors = true;
   $msg = '';

   foreach($_POST AS $key => $value)
   {
      $$key = is_string($value) ? trim($value) : $value;
      if ($key != 'send')
      {
         $mail_body .= "<span>$key</span><span>$value</span>";
      }
   }
   if (empty($Name))
   {
       $noerrors = false;
       $msg .= "Please input Name";
   }
   if ($noerrors == false) 
   {
       #Errors have been found
       echo $msg;
   } 
   else 
   {
      #No errors, send mail
      #Get mailer from settings
      //...

      #Display message after mail is sent
      echo "Thank you!";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do that. The most reasonable solution I can think of is to use `if(empty(trim($name)){ // do something }` but from your code, I guess you can make use of javascript to set the value of the hidden field if that is an option to you or you can change your logic.